Python script to loop through an API JSON response object to extract relevant info
I am calling an API, asking for a specific sellerId (BBBBBBBB, say in the example below).
I wish to identify the last offerCSV value and the last stockCSV value for each product from the products array. I'm not doing this quite right, as I'm only getting a check on the first offer, if that doesn't match our seller, then the script is moving onto the next product, rather than carrying on looping through all offers.
For simplicity, I have stripped out our JSON response object. In reality it has further (extraneous for this question) fields. It also is likely to have additional products, and each product multiple (differing amounts) of offers.
Here is the API response:
{
  "timestamp": 1716286343003,
  "tokensLeft": 1,
  "refillIn": 2,
  "refillRate": 3,
  "tokenFlowReduction": 0,
  "tokensConsumed": 5,
  "processingTimeInMs": 2,
  "products": [
      {
        "title": "Example Title",
        "asin": "ASINVALUE",
        "packageHeight": 53,
        "packageLength": 97,
        "packageWidth": 77,
        "packageWeight": 315,
        "packageQuantity": 1,
        "offers": [
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "AAAAAAAA",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024102,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7024470,
              8
            ]
          },
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "BBBBBBBB",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024470,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7031828,
              4
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Example Title 2",
        "asin": "ASINVALUE2",
        "packageHeight": 53,
        "packageLength": 97,
        "packageWidth": 77,
        "packageWeight": 315,
        "packageQuantity": 1,
        "offers": [
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "CCCCCCCC",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024102,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7024470,
              8
            ]
          },
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "BBBBBBBB",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024470,
              12345,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7031828,
              4
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

And here is the script as I've written in now:
async def test():
    try:
        # Upsert seller data and get associated ASINs
        asins = "B07K6FS97X"
        api_logger.info(f"Processing ASINs for seller: {asins}")

        # Iterate over each ASIN and fetch their respective product data
        product_data = api_response
        for asin in asins:
            try:
                api_logger.debug(f"Product data received for ASIN {asin}: {product_data}")  # Detailed log of the received data
                if 'products' in product_data:
                    for product in product_data['products']:
                        api_logger.info(f"Analyzing product data for ASIN: {product['asin']}")
                        found_matching_offer = False
                        offers = product.get('offers', [])
                        api_logger.info(f"Offers: {offers}")
                        for offer in product.get('offers', []):
                            api_logger.info(f"Analyzing offer from sellerID: {offer.get('sellerId')}")
                            if offer.get('sellerId') == seller_data['sellerId']:
                                found_matching_offer = True
                                stock_info = {
                                    "seller_id": seller_data['sellerId'],
                                    "asin": product['asin'],
                                    "record_date": datetime.now(timezone.utc),
                                    "stock_count": offer.get('stockCSV', [0])[-1],
                                    "stock_price": offer.get('offerCSV', [0, 0])[1]
                                }
                                api_logger.info(f"Found a matching offer for {product['asin']} for {seller_data['sellerId']}: stock count: {offer.get('stockCSV', [0])[-1]}")
                                break  # Found the matching seller's offer, no need to check further
                            if not found_matching_offer:
                                api_logger.warning(f"No matching offer found for seller ID {seller_data['sellerId']} and ASIN {product['asin']}")
                else:
                    api_logger.warning(f"No product data found for ASIN: {asin}")
            except Exception as exc:
                api_logger.error(f"Failed to process ASIN {asin}: {exc}")
    except Exception as e:
        api_logger.error(f"Error processing seller {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(test())

We are getting the function working, and confirming it is checking the first offer for each product, but then if it doesn't match our seller, it's just going straight into the product.
Any help very much appreciated!
I tried the above script, and desire the following output:

seller_id: BBBBBBBB (in this example, would change for each seller)
asin: ASINVALUE stock_count: 8 stock_price: 14435
seller_id: BBBBBBBB ASIN: ASINVALUE2 stock_count: 4 stock_price: 12345


Do you actually get a log for No matching offer found for seller ID {seller_data['sellerId']} and ASIN {product['asin']} when your program fails ?

On your example, the last values for offerCSV on both asins are 0, and your desired output shows the values before the 0, what is exactly the number you are looking for?

Hi Jamie, there's a few things to note:

asins should be an array, not a string.  At the moment it will loop through each individual character instead of each asin code.  on line 4 asins should be asins=["B07K6FS97X"]
on line 20 you're referencing seller_data but this hasn't been assigned anywhere above, may throw an error.

It's unclear how to diagnose without understanding the error/output from your existing code! cheers

Thank you everyone for your tips and help. I'm not quite there, but may post a revised question, as this was an offline (sandbox?) version of my code, which I modified due to not requesting directly from the API. However, to make it work I had to tweak the JSON etc. I will continue today and if I can't resolve edit the question for clarity. Thank you again

For your desire output:
data = {
  "timestamp": 1716286343003,
  "tokensLeft": 1,
  "refillIn": 2,
  "refillRate": 3,
  "tokenFlowReduction": 0,
  "tokensConsumed": 5,
  "processingTimeInMs": 2,
  "products": [
      {
        "title": "Example Title",
        "asin": "ASINVALUE",
        "packageHeight": 53,
        "packageLength": 97,
        "packageWidth": 77,
        "packageWeight": 315,
        "packageQuantity": 1,
        "offers": [
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "AAAAAAAA",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024102,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7024470,
              8
            ]
          },
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "BBBBBBBB",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024470,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7031828,
              4
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Example Title 2",
        "asin": "ASINVALUE2",
        "packageHeight": 53,
        "packageLength": 97,
        "packageWidth": 77,
        "packageWeight": 315,
        "packageQuantity": 1,
        "offers": [
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "CCCCCCCC",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024102,
              14435,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7024470,
              8
            ]
          },
          {
            "lastSeen": 7038020,
            "sellerId": "BBBBBBBB",
            "offerCSV": [
              7024470,
              12345,
              0
            ],
            "stockCSV": [
              7031828,
              4
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

seller_id = "BBBBBBBB"

asins = {asin: {"offerCSV": offer_val[-2], "stockCSV": stock_val[-1]} 
         for asin, offer_val, stock_val in 
         [(product["asin"], offer["offerCSV"], offer["stockCSV"]) 
          for product in data["products"] 
          for offer in product["offers"] if offer["sellerId"] == seller_id]}


for asin, values in asins.items():
    print(f"seller_id: {seller_id} ASIN: {asin}, Offer CSV: {values['offerCSV']}, Stock CSV: {values['stockCSV']}")

output:
seller_id: BBBBBBBB ASIN: ASINVALUE, Offer CSV: 14435, Stock CSV: 4
seller_id: BBBBBBBB ASIN: ASINVALUE2, Offer CSV: 12345, Stock CSV: 4

But note that the value for offerCSV is the second from last and not the last, to fit your desire (the last value is 0)

Thank you everyone for your tips and help. I'm not quite there, but may post a revised question, as this was an offline (sandbox?) version of my code, which I modified due to not requesting directly from the API. However, to make it work I had to tweak the JSON etc. I will continue today and if I can't resolve edit the question for clarity. Thank you again
